# Is there a way to manually set order of bar plot in R ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm doing some data analysis for an organization and I'm trying to change the order of the bars in a bar chart. Right now, it is ordered alphabetically but I want to set it to the order of days in a week. I have tried using levels and factor, but I don't think it is working possibly because I am reading the data in from an excel file and each column is the sum of all values of that day. Is there a way to do this through ggplot2 without editing the original excel file?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nygvj.png)

Comment: An ordered factor is the standard way to do this and there are a bunch of answers on this site that demonstrate how to do that. It will be easier to help if you review those and can share some specific code that isn't working.

Comment: The idea is `ggplot(df, aes(factor(x = day_of_week))) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'))`
But posting your code will help

Comment: Please see the **newer** answers in the linked duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

Basically do something like `ggplot(df,aes(x=factor(V1,level=unique(V1)),y=V3,fill=V2))` (or add `fct_rev` to reverse the order):

```
t=read.table("https://pastebin.com/raw/GyEiXxNs",r=1)
t=t[,c(4,1,3,2)]
colnames(t)=paste0("V",1:ncol(t)) # prevent ggplot from reordering the bars for each column
t=t[order(as.matrix(t)%*%(1:ncol(t))^2),] # reorder rows so that rows with a high percentage of the first column are placed first

w2l=function(x)data.frame(V1=rownames(x)[row(x)],V2=colnames(x)[col(x)],V3=unname(c(unlist(x))))
t2=w2l(t) # wide to long

lab=round(100*t2$V3)
lab[lab<=1]="" # don't display labels for 0% or 1%

ggplot(t2,aes(x=fct_rev(factor(V1,levels=unique(V1))),y=V3,fill=V2))+
geom_bar(stat="identity",width=1,position=position_fill(reverse=T),size=.1,color="gray10")+
geom_text(aes(label=lab),position=position_stack(vjust=.5,reverse=T),size=3.5)+
coord_flip()+
scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0))+
scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0))+
scale_fill_manual(values=colorspace::hex(colorspace::HSV(head(seq(0,360,length.out=ncol(t)+1),-1),.5,1)))+
# ggh4x::force_panelsizes(cols=unit(3,"in"))+ # make bars always 3 inches wide
theme(
  axis.text=element_text(color="black",size=11),
  axis.text.x=element_blank(),
  axis.ticks=element_blank(),
  axis.title=element_blank(),
  legend.position="none",
  panel.border=element_rect(color="gray10",fill=NA,size=.2)
)

ggsave("1.png",width=4.5,height=.25*nrow(t)+.3,limitsize=F)
```

[image]